# For...of es6 - how about getting index?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say we have an array "myArray" and we want to iterate over it using the for..of. We are searching for a specific value and when we find it, we want to return the index where the value was. So, i have this:

```
var myArray=[1,2,3,4,5];
for (let item of myArray) {
    if (item===3) {
        //return index?
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the index? Thanks.

Comment: This is a question easily answered by a [quick search online](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=js%20index%20of%20item%20in%20array)

Comment: If the goal is index, why not just use simple `for` loop? Or a forEach?

Comment: OzW thank you for your response, i assume you down-voted the question. However, i am not asking how to do this in JavaScript period, i am asking how to do this with the new `for... of`. You know, learning something new.

Comment: I think your question does not show effort. A very quick search online would lead you to [some solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which you can try.

Comment: If I'd want to return the index I'd probably make a simple for. I wanted to know if it is possible in `for...of` to retrieve the index as well. That's all. I provided a very basic example. I haven't found anywhere on the web a resource that would answer 'yes' or 'no' . however it does appear that someone else asked this before me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not come out of the box, but you may employ the new [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), which returns an iterator over the `index-value` pairs:

```
for (const [index, value] of myArray.entries()) {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively you could use the new [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which accepts a predicate and returns an index of the first element that matches it. Eg:

```
myArray.findIndex(v => v > 10); // would return an index of a first value
                                // that is greater than 10
```